# Solving algebraic equations for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

So I was able to find the least common denominator which is $12$ but I'm struggling to solving the equation: $$\frac{4(x - 2)}{6} - \frac{2(x + 4)}{4} = -\frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $6\times4=24$ then proceed with usual simplifications.

Comment: @Hakim : Multiplying by $12$ works just as well.  $12$ is the smallest common multiply of $6$, $4$, and $3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Indeed.

Comment: I should not have missed this but I did: If you reduce the fractions to lowest terms first, then $6$ is the smallest common denominator.

Comment: Notice that the fraction with $2(something)/4$ is the same as one half, which is the same as $3/6$. Then, the LHS becomes $(something)/6$. From here, you could cross multiply, or do whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $12$ gives you
$$12\times\frac{4(x - 2)}{6} - 12\times \frac{2(x + 4)}{4} =12\times\frac{-2}{3}\iff 8(x-2)-6(x+4)=-8.$$

Comment: So after getting the 8(x - 2) - 6(x + 4) = -8. Do I then solve it by 8 * x = 8x and 8 * -2 = -16 and so forth until it reaches a fraction

Comment: @lase: Yes. By expanding them, you'll get $8x-8\times 2-6x-6\times 4=-8$.

Comment: so it would be 8x - 16 - 6x - 24 = -8. and then you combine them to like terms

Comment: @lase: Yes. $8x-6x=-8+16+24$.

Comment: I completely forgot how to get the 8 and the 6. I got a different number instead

Comment: $\frac{12\times 4}{6}=\frac{\color{red}{6}\times 2\times 4}{\color{red}{6}}=\frac{1\times 2\times 4}{1}=8$ and $\frac{12\times 2}{4}=\frac{3\times \color{red}{4}\times 2}{\color{red}{4}}=\frac{3\times 1\times 2}{1}=6$.